# Why is velocity inversely related to pressure in a flow?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure, speed, bernoulli-equation

I've seen the equations that give this relationship, and I understand the math and have seen it worked out in problems. But I don't have a qualitative, conceptual grasp on the relationship.

Is the pressure that which is exerted by a small element of the flow, or exerted on a small element? Maybe it is the pressure exerted on or by the boundary?

And once pressure is defined, why is it related to velocity? Why does something push less if you speed it up? I would have guessed a faster flow pushes harder.

Answer (score 4):

Be careful with directions. Usually the pressure although not a vector, can be understood as $F/A$, where $F$ is the magnitude of the force. However this one does have a direction associated to it. For the Bernoulli equation one is normally interested in the horizontal speed of the fluid and the pressure due to changes in height. With the picture I described in mind, particles with a horizontal velocity, hitting a vertical wall lead to $P$ proportional to $v$. While a horizontal surface under a fluid with horizontal speed, indeed experiences less pressure above it, you can think of less particles having the chance to hit (transfer momentum) to the surface since the are mostly traveling horizontally.

Answer (score 1):

You say "if you speed it up".
*Who* speeds it up?

The only thing that can speed it up is a pressure difference.
(Let's do it horizontally, so we can ignore gravity.)

That's why less pressure means higher velocity, and vice-versa.

Comment: I don't think this really addresses his question. Bernoulli's principle says that fluid in motion has less static pressure than fluid that isn't motion, nothing to do with pressure differences causing velocity changes. Also i think there's a duplicate here which didn't get a great answer as well http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/165375/what-is-basically-the-difference-between-static-pressure-and-dynamic-pressure

Comment: @mikedunlavey. So correct me if I am missunderstanding but you are saying pressure is defined as at the fluid boundaries pushing in. So if you had, say, a nozzle. You have less pressure at the outlet than inlet so you have a net force that speeds up the flow? And so if the pressure actually increased over the control volume you would see a net force towards the inlet but a net velocity towards the outlet. So the flow would be decelerating and that explains why more pressure generally means a slower flow?

Comment: @YogiDMT: The OP wanted an intuitive explanation. Bernoulli's principle is  nothing more than conservation of momentum $F=ma$ in a fluid. (It also conserves energy. I can point you to the reason why, if you need it.)  Consider a small cubical parcel of fluid. If the pressure on the left side is incrementally greater than on the right side, it will feel a net incremental force, so it will accelerate to the right, giving an increment of velocity (per time). Integrate that, and you get the relationship between pressure and velocity.

Comment: @BoddTaxter: The velocity of flow in the combustion chamber follows the inverse of the pressure. Sure you can insert heat, and thus pressure, part way down the combustion chamber of the rocket. Unless things are supersonic, that additional pressure immediately propagates to the inlet (by the same mechanism) until the inlet is at that same pressure. Then the difference exists no longer.

Answer (score 1):

The "pressure is inversely related to velocity" formula is applied when fluid is in dynamic motion and $P =f/a$ as area is inversely to velocity. Instead, in $P = fv$ pressure is directly proportional to velocity and it is applied only on static fluid

$P〆v$ in static fluid
$P〆1/v$ in dynamic fluid